# Co-worker takes up my time talking and asking advice?

Tags: colleagues, time-management

I am relatively new to my job and my co-worker has been there many years. For the past 5 months she has been taking up my time, while at work, with her personal problems and I feel I will get in trouble. She, on the other hand, doesn't seem to care. How can I ask her nicely, without hurting her feelings that we should talk after work hours?

Answer (score 5):

For me I would politely state: "hey, can we catch up later on, I have to get through this work right now" and perhaps see her at a break/lunch time?
If this doesn't get the message across you may then need to take the next step in mentioning it to your line manager during a progress meeting, it is their duty to ensure you can work with as little distraction as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I simply say with a smile "I am sorry but I have a deadline to meet, they're breathing down my neck and my butt is on fire" And I follow up immediately by getting back to work.

If I want to take up her personal subjects after hours, I'll initiate that conversation myself on my own. Not that I might want to if I know ahead of time that she's got a motor mouth and that she is close to unstoppable once she starts and revs up her engines :)